# How to create a dynamic where clause in sql?

Tags: sql, teradata

So I have created a table that has the following columns from a transaction table with all customer purchase records:
1. Month-Year, 2.Customer ID, 3. Number of Transactions in that month.

I'm trying to create a table that has the output of 
1. Month-Year, 2. Number of active customers defined by having at least 1 purchase in the previous year.

The code that I have currently is this but the case when obviously only capturing one date and the where clause isn't dynamic. Would really appreciate your help.

```
select month_start_date, cust_ID, 
(case when month_start_Date between date and add_months(date, -12) then count(cust_ID) else 0 end) as active
from myserver.mytable
where
month_start_Date>add_months(month_start_date,-12)
group by 1,2
```

EDIT: I'm just trying to put a flag next to a customer if they are active in each month defined as having at least one transaction in the last year thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by a "dynamic `WHERE` clause"?

Comment: Which part do you want to make "dynamic"?  You could use a parameter to specify a minimum data but it's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to put a flag next to a customer if they are active in each month defined as having at least one transaction in the last year thanks!

Comment: You want to count the customer even if there's no transaction in a specific month, but within the previous 12 months?

Comment: Yes exactly- I want to define active flag as at least 1 transaction in the past year. My code date range isn't dynamic so it doesnt do what I want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use Teradata's proprietary `EXPAND ON` synax for creating time series:

```
SELECT month_start_date, COUNT(*)
FROM
 ( -- create one row for every month within the next year
   -- after a customer's transaction  
   SELECT DISTINCT
      BEGIN(pd) AS month_start_date, 
      cust_ID
   FROM myserver.mytable
   EXPAND ON PERIOD(month_start_date, ADD_MONTHS(month_start_date,12)) AS pd
       BY ANCHOR MONTH_BEGIN         -- every 1st of month
       FOR PERIOD (DATE - 500, DATE) -- use this to restrict to a specific date range
 ) AS dt
GROUP BY month_start_date
ORDER BY month_start_date
```

Comment: Dnoeth, do you mind explaining to me what the period command at the end does? I realized that expand just creates copies for each rows for the next 12 months but isnt the first period(month_start_date, add_months(month_start_date, 12)) doing that already?  I'm just not sure what the last period(date-500, date) does. I changed it to 365 without knowledge off what it accomplishes.

Comment: @Analyst: It's optionsl, it restricts the rows returned to this date range, e.g. the period covers ten years but you onlywant dates from two specific years returned.